# Unable to pass references from frontend to backend in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

I have a frontend tree structure which I use to display in a WPF list box in my front end module.

```
public class Root
{
    public string Name;
    public List<Root> Children;
    public Root(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        Children = new List<Root>();
    }

    public void AddChild(Root rootObject)
    {
        Children.Add(rootObject);
    }

}

public class Unit : Root { }
public class SubUnit : Root { }
public class Platoon : Root { }
public class Section : Root { }
```

The SubUnit and Platoon Objects have additional fields for unique values which I have omitted for simplicity.

This is all working fine until I try to populate this list fromwithing my backend. What I want to acomplish is call a function on my backend unit object which will recurse the backend and return a list to the frontend.

My backend has the following design structure, which can be fluid as needed. Again the unique fields have been left out of this example for clarity.

```
BackendUnit 
{
  BackEndSubUnit SubUnit;
} 

BackEndSubUnit
{
  List<BackEndPlatoon> MyPlatoonns;
  List<BackEndSubUnit> MySubUnits;
}

BackEndPlatoon
{
  List<BackEndSection MySections;
}

BackEndSection
{
}
```

The idea is the frontend does not need to know anything about the backend structure, and as long.  Where I am struggling is how to make the frontend structure visible to the backend so that my recursive methods can populate it in the backend and pass the populated list back to the front end to display.